# display xml code in a table with php

Tags: php, xml

I want it to display something like

concept type  Relation type Code from XML file showing the nodes and child elements

I can get it to display in an array in the table but I don't know how to display it in xml format so it is easier to read.

my php file is

```
    <?php
#error_reporting(0);
#header("Content-type: text/xml");

$get = ('Human.cogxml');
$cogxml = simplexml_load_file($get);
$data = $cogxml->support->conceptTypes->ctype;
$datas = $cogxml->support->relationTypes->rtype;
?>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>Concept Name</th>
                <th>Relation Type</th>
                <th>CoGui XML</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
            <?php echo $row['label']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($datas as $row2) {
                        ?>
                        <td>
                    <?php echo $row2['label'];  ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            header('Content-type text/xml');
                            #dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                            $file = file_get_contents('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless');
                               $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
                               echo '<pre>';
print_r($movies);
echo '<pre>';
                            # echo $dom->XML();
                             ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
            }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

My xml file is

```
<cogxml>
    <namespace name="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#" prefix=""/>
    <support name="vocabulary">
        <conceptTypes>
            <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841" label="Human" x="10" y="10">
                <translation descr="" label="Human" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
            <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_ef8dc30a-fc37-48fa-80f3-4588e4d101d2" label="Adult" x="120" y="10">
                <translation descr="" label="Adult" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
            <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_1b5b2797-a707-4758-a200-6e9bef2f13b9" label="Female" x="90" y="110">
                <translation descr="" label="Female" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
            <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_be05db54-5043-488c-a08b-3bb643cf0f78" label="Child" x="130" y="60">
                <translation descr="" label="Child" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
            <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_8a7f45ec-0204-4c73-921b-781d87327ba0" label="Girl" x="170" y="220">
                <translation descr="" label="Girl" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
                <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_199f3367-213f-4139-8ad4-fe2f4e4874e7" label="Woman" x="235" y="130">
                <translation descr="" label="Woman" lang="en"/>
            </ctype>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_ef8dc30a-fc37-48fa-80f3-4588e4d101d2" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_1b5b2797-a707-4758-a200-6e9bef2f13b9" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_be05db54-5043-488c-a08b-3bb643cf0f78" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_8a7f45ec-0204-4c73-921b-781d87327ba0" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_1b5b2797-a707-4758-a200-6e9bef2f13b9"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_199f3367-213f-4139-8ad4-fe2f4e4874e7" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_1b5b2797-a707-4758-a200-6e9bef2f13b9"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_8a7f45ec-0204-4c73-921b-781d87327ba0" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_be05db54-5043-488c-a08b-3bb643cf0f78"/>
            <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_199f3367-213f-4139-8ad4-fe2f4e4874e7" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_ef8dc30a-fc37-48fa-80f3-4588e4d101d2"/>
        </conceptTypes>
        <relationTypes>
            <rtype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_rt_336363f1-0068-48d1-b1de-93ae264e4f49" idSignature="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841 http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_5f3287f9-fb7b-47c2-84b0-e25694b29841" label="Link">
                <translation descr="" label="Link" lang="en"/>
            </rtype>
         </relationTypes>
        <nestingTypes>
            <ntype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_nt_23d8104c-fbe5-4228-895f-074faa673d74" label="Nesting">
                <translation descr="" label="Nesting" lang="en"/>
            </ntype>
        </nestingTypes>
        <conformity/>
        <modules/>
    </support>
    <localeTypes name="undefined_vocabulary">
        <conceptTypes/>
        <relationTypes/>
        <nestingTypes/>
        <conformity/>
        <modules/>
    </localeTypes>
    <graph id="_g1" label="_g1" nature="fact" set="default_set"/>
</cogxml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `print_r($movies);` you could do this:

```
echo $movies->asXML();
```

Find more in [this PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php).

**- EDIT -**

I thought about it and maybe if you replace the whole `file_get_contents()` thing with the following, it might work:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless');
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

I mean from the `$file` line to the `print_r($movie)` line.

**- END EDIT -**

**- EDIT 2-**

If the XML doesn't show up but it appears on the source code, then try wrapping it with the `<pre>` tag.

```
<td>
    <pre>
        <?php
            header('Content-type text/xml');
            #dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless');
            echo $doc->saveXML();
        ?>
    </pre>
</td>
```

**- END EDIT 2 -**

Comment: Ok thanks I have tried that as well but that doesn't bring up the xml nodes. Like for example <ctype>.

Comment: @Charlotte Alright... well, `file_get_contents()` is supposed to return a string and for example it returns JSON perfectly as is, that's why we need to use `json_encode()` to display it as a PHP array. Did you try simply outputting that to see what you get so we can check if there is actually anything we should do to such string?

Comment: @Charlotte I updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks I've just tried this but I just get an empty cell in the table. I've echoed $movies as xml but nothing seems to appear. But when I view the source for that page the xml is there. Do you know how I get it to appear?

Comment: If I understood well, you are telling me it worked but it doesn't show up. In such case, wrap the XML (you'll have to wrap your PHP embed code) with the HTML `<pre>` tag. I'll update my answer to show you how.

Comment: Ok Thank you all for your help I just got it working with that now.

Comment: @Charlotte That's awesome! I am glad you could make it work, good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

By default [SimpleXMLElement()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) expects a string and not URL or file path. Specifically the `data_is_url` argument is set to `False`. Therefore, explicitly pass a `True` value if reading from file:

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($file, 0, true);
```

But if reading from URL, no need for `file_get_contents()`:

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless', NULL, True);
```

Additionally, `print_f($movies)` dumps the structure of SimpleXMLElement object which may not be too intuitive for users. Consider using `asxml()` or `saveXML()` to output XML content as is to screen:

```
echo $movies -> asXML();
```

OR

```
echo $movies -> saveXML();
```